# How can I optimize my code for more performance?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

My question more conceptual. I have been [read guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/), [API on the site](http://emberjs.com/api/) and looked [some slides](https://speakerdeck.com/lukemelia/), but I haven't confidence by my decision. I made component, but it seems it may be better.

I worried about many tags `<script id="metamorph-73-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>`

**Question 1:** How can I reduce it?

**Question 2:** Is true that count tags == count event listeners?

Thanks!

**Templates:**

> ```
> <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/bootstrap-select">
>     <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-mini" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
>         {{selected_name}} <span class="caret"></span>
>     </a>
>     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
>         {{#each items}}
>             <li {{action "chosen" this.id this.name on="click" }}><a href="#">{{this.name}}</a></li>
>         {{/each}}
>     </ul>
> </script>
>
> <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/filter-offers">
>         <span class="label_filter">Фильтр </span>
>             {{bootstrap-select name="filter_day" data=App.CONSTANTS.DAYS_OF_WEEK selected=0}}
>             {{bootstrap-select name="filter_city" data=App.CONSTANTS.CITIES selected=2}}
>             {{bootstrap-select name="filter_section" data=App.CONSTANTS.SECTION selected=1}}
>         </div>
> </script>
> ```

**JavaScript:**

> ```
> App.BootstrapSelectComponent = Em.Component.extend({
>     tagName: 'div',
>     classNames: ['ember-view', 'btn-group'],
>     // custom fileds
>     name: '',
>     data: [],
>     items: function(){
>         return this.get('data').map(function(row){
>             return Em.Object.create({id: row[0], name: row[1]});
>         });
>     }.property('data'),
>     selected: NaN,
>     selected_name: function(){
>         var id = this.get('selected'),
>             item = this.get('items').filter(function(item, index){
>                 if (item.id == id) return true;
>             });
>         if (item[0] && 'name' in item[0])
>             return item[0]['name'];
>         else
>             return '';
>     }.property('selected'), 
>     // setup actions
>     action_name: function(){
>         var name = 'select_updated_' + this.get('name');
>         return name.camelize();
>     }.property(),
>     actions: {
>         chosen: function(value, name) {
>             // save to memory
>             this.set('selected', value);
>             // bubble action
>             this.sendAction('action_name',
>                             this.get('selected'),
>                             this.get('selected_name'));
>         }
>     }
> });
>
> App.FilterOffersComponent = Em.Component.extend({
>     init: function() {
>         this._super();
>     },
>     templateName: 'filter-offers',
>     didInsertElement: function(){
>         //console.log(this.get('childViews').mapProperty('selected'));    
>     },
>     // setup actions
>     action: function(){
>         // by default filterOffersUpdated
>         var name = this.get('templateName') + '_updated';
>         return name.camelize();
>     }.property('templateName'),
>     actions: {
>         selectUpdatedFilterDay: function(){
>             this.sendAction('action');
>         },
>         selectUpdatedFilterCity: function(){
>             this.sendAction('action');
>         },
>         selectUpdatedFilterSection: function(){
>             this.sendAction('action');
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your concern isn't necessary. Number of tags does not necessarily mean number of action listeners. Some tags are listeners, some aren't. You have just the right amount: 1 per element.

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I looked for answers about it. Thanks